# Update method assigns the value first time but when the update method is called second time, that value is lost

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is a bit of a code:

```
public class Script_Console: MonoBehaviour {
    public string clickedButtonName;
    public string save_click_name;

    void Update() {
        save_click_name = clickedButtonName;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Before: printing in update method save click name" +save_click_name);
    }
}
```

I am trying to assign `clickedButtonName` to `save_click_name` but unable to get the value the second time.

Comment: It would help if you copy and pasted your results from the console. Also, it may help to add a line just under the void update() { line that prints clickedButtonName.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear with your question, but `save_click_name` should have whatever name is set in `clickedButtonName`. You can try the sample below for clarity

```
void Update () {
    if(save_click_name != clickedButtonName)
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Before: printing in update method save click name" + save_click_name);

    save_click_name = clickedButtonName;

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)) {
        int rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,10);
        clickedButtonName = "something " + rand.ToString();
    }
}
```